# Pandas: convert column of dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have df

```
ID month
0       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-02 
1       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-03  
2       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-04  
3       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-05  
4       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-06  
5       0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118    2014-07
```

and I try to turn `year_month` to datetime.
I use `df1['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.month)` 
but it return `ValueError: Unknown string format`
how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a format string `'%Y-%m'` as [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can't deduce the format from your string:

```
In [42]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y-%m')
df

Out[42]:
                                 ID    month       date
0  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-02 2014-02-01
1  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-03 2014-03-01
2  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-04 2014-04-01
3  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-05 2014-05-01
4  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-06 2014-06-01
5  0001ee12f919a1b570658024bb59d118  2014-07 2014-07-01

In [43]:
df.info()           

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
ID       6 non-null object
month    6 non-null object
date     6 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I have a problem and with this string `ValueError: time data '\\N' does match format specified`

Comment: Well then you have duff data, you can force the conversion by doing: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y-%m', errors='coerce')` to force the errant values to `NaT`

Comment: How can I turn it to this form: `YYYY-MM` ?

Comment: @jezrael, can you say, how can I convert `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYY-MM`? I try `df1['date'] = [w[:6] for w in df1['date']]` but it return me `TypeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Why do you want this? here you get a `datetime` dtype, you can't get that format in the displayed output without converting it to a string, and if you do that it's no different to what you started with

Comment: I need to use next `df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1 = df1.groupby('ID').resample('M').size().reset_index(name='val')` but I need this dataframe only with month

Comment: I need to create value `val` and use it only with month. I don't need every day. Earlier I use `df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month)
df.set_index('month', inplace=True)


df = df.groupby('ID').resample('D').size().reset_index(name='val')` and it works well. But now I have a problem

Comment: Your problem bears no resemblance to your question, I suggest accepting my answer and posting a new question with raw data, code and desired output