# How to convert an object column into datetime for pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a `df` column with two columns, `df.info()` yields the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 200 entries, 0 to 199
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date          200 non-null object
all_events    200 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 3.2+ KB
```

**Question:**

How can convert the `df['date']` into a `datetime` object?

**Relevant Research:**

- [Pandas: convert column of dataframe to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016627/pandas-convert-column-of-dataframe-to-datetime)
- [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)
- [Converting object column in pandas dataframe to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898826/converting-object-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-datetime)

**What I have tried:**

- `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)`
- `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`
- `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

**Problem:**

whatever I have I tried, I always get the following message:

`TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Answer (score 0):

If all entries in your *date* column had form like *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* then
*pd.to_datetime(df['date'])* would be enough (this function is "clever"
enough to discover the proper format).

Apparently you have some "exceptional" values, with different formatting,
which can not be converted to *datetime*.

Note that one of parameters of *to_datetime* is *errors* with default value of
*raise*, meaning "raise an exception in case of any error".

So try e.g. tu run *pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')* to convert such "exceptional"
values to *NaT*.

Then check which output rows contain such value and take a look at corresponding
rows in the source DataFrame (or e.g. in a file which you read this DataFrame from).
Most likely you will find what is wrong in your input and decide how to correct
these errors.